# Regional Date format in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a strange issues with date formatting  - I am formatting dates as per below consistently - trying to get and display file details, below works fine with ldn / other settings.

However, one of the user got French date time setting, and below code fails format datetime and file size.

Not sure what is the best way to handle all regions?   Any suggestions pls?

> invalid FR format - 02-d꣭2019 15:23:10 , fileSize  = 110,00 , instead
>   of 110.00

```
fileSize = FileLen(tool) / 1024
creationDate = Format(Local2GMT(.getFile(tool).DateCreated), "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")
modifiedDate = Format(Local2GMT(.getFile(tool).DateLastModified), "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")
accessfileDate = Format(Local2GMT(.getFile(tool).DateLastAccessed), "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")

Function Local2GMT(dtLocalDate As Date) As Date
    Local2GMT = DateAdd("s", -GetLocalToGMTDifference(), dtLocalDate)
End Function
```

Comment: The safest bet I've tried between language-versions is to build the string completely.  `year()`, `month()`, and `Day()`, etc., appending the outputs into the desired string.  That refers to the date aspect only.  Have not attempted the filesize aspect.

Comment: I believe `NumberValue()` will provide the appropriate filesize comparison.  See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.numbervalue).

Comment: Thanks Cyril - I tried below -- but gets invalid dates - any idea?   ?format(day(date),"DD") & "-" & format(month(date),"MMM") & "-" & format(year(date),"YYYY")
10-Jan-1905

Comment: My only quick guess without testing (and I don't have a non-English version) would be to use lower case "dd" and "yyyy" in case that has an impact.  Sorry that didn't work out for you!  [See documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications).

Comment: Thanks  a lot - I will give it a go - and update you.

Comment: Didn't work either - ?format(now(),"[$-en-EN]mmm dd, yyyy")
f?vr 19, 2020